PipeWire fails to create nodes for all ALSA devices
Ubuntu and downstream of it, just recently Mint, moved from PulseAudio to PipeWire. I'm trying to familiarise myself with configs and problem is that I have four distinct sound sinks on my MintBox 2 and I can see all of them and an extra two on ALSA:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [RX-A760]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [SONY TV]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCM2702 [Burr-Brown Japan PCM2702], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

There are sufficient clues here for me to describe my sound devices clearly, and I'll adopt a card/device nomenclature that ALSA's aplay uses for identifying them (ALSA lieks to write CARD=PCH,DEV=3 and I'll write PCH/3):
So I have:

PCH/0 being a headphone jack with a 3.5mm stereo audio socket and device attached
PCH/3 being a Yamaha RX-A760 Audovisual Receiver
PCH/7 being a Sony Bravia Television
PCM2702/1 being a USB Audio device (Burr-Brown based)

ALSA also identifies devices that have no interface on the MintBox 2 but I presume are supported by the board:

PCH/1 presumably for an S/PDIF digital port that is not present on the case but the HDA Intel PCH board supports
PCH/8 presumably a third HDMI port that again does not exist on the case but the HDA Intel PCH board supports

Those two I can gladly ignore.
But when I look at PipeWire:
$ pw-cli ls Node
    id 29, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "29"
        factory.id = "10"
        priority.driver = "20000"
        node.name = "Dummy-Driver"
    id 30, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "30"
        factory.id = "10"
        priority.driver = "19000"
        node.name = "Freewheel-Driver"
    id 39, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "39"
        factory.id = "10"
        client.id = "35"
        priority.session = "100"
        priority.driver = "1"
        node.name = "Midi-Bridge"
        media.class = "Midi/Bridge"
    id 48, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "48"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:front:1:playback"
        factory.id = "18"
        client.id = "35"
        device.id = "44"
        priority.session = "1009"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        node.description = "PCM2702 16-bit stereo audio DAC Analog Stereo"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_Japan_Burr-Brown_Japan_PCM2702-00.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "Burr-Brown Japan PCM2702"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
    id 53, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "153"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:front:0:capture"
        factory.id = "18"
        client.id = "35"
        device.id = "43"
        priority.session = "2009"
        priority.driver = "2009"
        node.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo.3"
        node.nick = "ALC1150 Analog"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
    id 54, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "152"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hdmi:0:playback"
        factory.id = "18"
        client.id = "35"
        device.id = "43"
        priority.session = "696"
        priority.driver = "696"
        node.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo"
        node.nick = "RX-A760"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
    id 61, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
        object.serial = "272"
        factory.id = "6"
        client.id = "59"
        client.api = "pipewire-pulse"
        application.name = "ALSA plug-in [kodi.bin]"
        node.name = "ALSA plug-in [kodi.bin]"
        media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio"
        media.category = "Manager"

I can see Pipewire has created a pile of nodes I have no interest in (A Dunny-Driver, a Freewheel-Driver, a Midi/Bridge) and that it has two nodes for my Yamaha RX-A760 (54 for the device proper with an ALSA path, and 61 which Kodi currently playing on the RX-A760). We can ignore the latter and observe that Pipewire only finds 2 of my four sound sinks and confuses one of them as a source. I can map the ALSA IDs then to PipeWire node IDs (which I will denote PW/id):

PCH/0 -> PW/53 - though it has only a Source node. This device of course is a RealTek ALC1150 chip which is indeed represented on the case by both a microphone and a headphone jack. Ironically, I have nothing plugged in to the microphone jack, but a device into the headphone jack and I expect an Audio/Sink node.
PCH/3 -> PW/54
PCH/7 -> Absent, Pipewire has no node for this!
PCM2702/1 -> PW/48

So, I have two salient questions:

Why does PipeWire not create a node for PCH/7. To be clear there is a Sony Bravia attached and it is on when I do these tests and in fact is one of screens I can use on the box and I can play sound through it on my Mint system (it appears in Cinnamon Sound Settings). But what is up with PipeWire here?
Why does PipeWire create an Audio/Source for my microphone jack and nor an Audio/Sink for the headphone jack? Again, I can play sound through that on my Mint system (it appears in Cinnamon Sound Settings). But what is up with PipeWire here?

I'm keen to understand PulseWire better and what is going on here. Not least because WirePlumber reflects this problem also sees just the two sinks:
$ wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, cookie:2258751752]
 └─ Clients:
        32. xdg-desktop-portal                  [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:121629]
        33. cinnamon-settings.py                [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:267176]
        34. WirePlumber                         [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:269937]
        35. WirePlumber [export]                [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:269937]
        42. PulseAudio systray                  [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:1821]
        47. wpctl                               [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:380732]
        59. ALSA plug-in [kodi.bin]             [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:7]
        63. Blueman                             [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:1848]
        64. Cinnamon Volume Control Media Keys  [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:1508]
        65. cinnamon                            [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:267176]
        66. Cinnamon Volume Control             [1.0.5, polyphemus@cyclops, pid:1689]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      43. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │      44. PCM2702 16-bit stereo audio DAC     [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      48. PCM2702 16-bit stereo audio DAC Analog Stereo [vol: 0.40]
 │  *   54. Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI) [vol: 0.66]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   53. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:
        61. ALSA plug-in [kodi.bin]                                     
             60. output_FL       > RX-A760:playback_FL  [active]
             74. output_FR       > RX-A760:playback_FR  [active]

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo

We see the two sinks 48 and 54 and the Source 53 for which I'd like a sink (the headphone jack) and the missing PCH/7 sink!
